# Angular and your own js library integration, best practises

Tags: angular, typescript

Say I wanted to write a typescript function that can be used across components, services, modules what have you.

For the sake of argument, let's say it is an alert wrapper, something like

`my_alert(msg); // function my_alert(msg) { alert(msg); }`

And there are quite of a few of these functions which form a library of yours, say, my-handy-js-library.js.

What is the best way to handle this task in angular? This would not be a service. right?

Would you just create a js file and import it the same way hammer js is imported? If so, what would be the best location for it? Should it be ts file, to begin with?

Comment: Have you considered writing an angular module written in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I'm always having a separate folder in src and adding all my files there. And because everything in the Angular application is in TypeScript so it'll be better to keep this one also in TypeScript.

Of course not all your functions should be in a service. Use services when your functions are bound together and when together they have a specific behavior and are responsible for a specific thing. For example when your functions are responsible for getting some kind of related data.